# Is it possible to create a docker container that contains one or more containers?

Tags: docker

I want to create a docker container which contains one or more containers.
Is it possible with Docker?

Comment: Why would you do that ? Are you going to implement in a Docker container a new type of container ? In my opinion Docker is not designed for this purpose but is rather a platform for developers enabling portability and compatibility with others applications.

Comment: I have 4 containers, each depends on one another. I want to create an image by adding only one(the most dependent) container. So, what I expect is, like, for ex: A,B,C,D are containers. dependency goes like this, A->B->C->D.
I want to only include D & so the rest can be done automatically.

Comment: Hum I'm getting it ! I don't think it's a good practice because if you're able to do that then included containers (A,B,C in D if I'm right) will not be accessible from other containers ... And you are loosing the sharing principle of Docker, aren't you ? Why don't you wanna pack 4 containers and deploy them in a Docker instance, you really need only one image ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To run docker inside docker is definitely possible. The main thing is that you `run` the outer container with [extra privileges](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration) (starting with `--privileged=true`) and then install docker in that container.

Check this blog post for more info: [Docker-in-Docker](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/).

One potential use case for this is described in [this entry](https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/building-docker-images-within-docker-containers-via-jenkins/). The blog describes how to build docker containers within a Jenkins docker container.

However, Docker inside Docker it is not the recommended approach to solve this type of problems. Instead, the recommended approach is to create "sibling" containers as [described in this post](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

Comment: FYI you do not need all the steps in that tutorial anymore. Just run your container as ```--privileged=true``` and then run ```apt-get install docker.io``` inside your container.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail - Excellent, thank you! It was I while since I did Docker-in-Docker.

Comment: "sibling" containers could lead to orphans in a way that nested containers cannot. Am I right? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47084681/14731.

Comment: How can i mention this in Dockerfile to create the image? @wassgren