# docker within docker, post http error

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am trying to run docker within docker. The sole purpose is experimental, I am by no means trying to implement anything functional, I just want to check how docker performs when it is run from another docker.

I start docker through boot2docker om my mac and then spin up a simple ubuntu image.

```
$ docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I then go ahead and install docker as well as python.

```
root@aa9263c874e4: apt-get update
root@aa9263c874e4: apt-get install -y docker.io python2.7
```

It is able to connect to the internet, because it performs this apt-get. I then get the following error when I am trying to start a docker instance from within docker:

```
root@aa9263c874e4: sudo docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
2015/01/09 08:59:09 Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

Any idea what I missed? It seems weird that I get a post error because it seems to be able to connect to the internet via apt-get before.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. The main thing is you need to run docker with the --privileged flag, but I think there are a couple of other gotchas. You're best trying this: https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind

Comment: And that post error is nothing to do with the internet, it's trying to talk to the docker socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question before on [howto run a Docker container inside Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721178/is-it-possible-to-create-a-docker-container-that-contains-one-or-more-containers/27721929#27721929).

> To run docker inside docker is definitely possible. The main thing is that you `run` the outer container with [extra privileges](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration) (starting with `--privileged=true`) and then install docker in that container.
>
> Check this blog post for more info: [Docker-in-Docker](http://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/).
>
> An excellent use case for this is described in [this entry](https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/building-docker-images-within-docker-containers-via-jenkins/). The blog describes how to build docker containers within a Jenkins docker container.

So, I believe that your `POST` problem has nothing to do with connecting to the internet since the container is trying to talk to the docker socket. To solve the problem, simply add the `--privileged=true` flag on the outer container when starting it, like this:

```
docker run --privileged=true ...
```

Comment: it didnt work for all containers, but this snippet with this container did the trick: ```docker run -t -i --privileged jpetazzo/dind```