# docker: Is it possible to start native windows sibling containers from within another?

Tags: windows, docker, native

Is it possible to start a native windows sibling container from within a [native windows container](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/)? So I don't mean docker-in-docker.

Like on [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker):

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** The latest Docker EE preview releases for Windows support bind-mounting the Docker API. Details here: https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/docker-windows-server-1709/

Yeah, there's a couple of steps though and it's not very elegant nor secure. You have to change the Windows Daemon config to listen on a public interface:

```
net stop docker
dockerd.exe --unregister-service
dockerd.exe -H npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine -H 0.0.0.0:2375 --register-service
net start docker
```

Now when starting containers, the Docker API will be available on the default gateway ip (you can find it with ipconfig) of the container, on port 2375.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of this? This seems like a pretty important scenario not documented online yet.

Comment: @deepelement in the latest previews, you can now mount Docker daemon named pipe too: https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/docker-windows-server-1709/

Comment: Looks like docker blog urls have changed... this is the updated link https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-windows-server-1709/