# Run docker inside docker to avoid installing multiple dependencies

Tags: docker

I'm in front of one dilemma that I'd like to discuss here to open a constructive discussion.

My use case is very simple:

I need to run a bash script which execute several commands like install `npm`, execute `aws-cli` and query PostgreSQL. For this last task I use `psql`. Easy task I'd say however Docker slightly complicate the situation.

The problem would be solved if I would create an image where I'd install all the dependencies. However the result would be a pretty big image and I'd not go with this solution.

What about to run the script with one Docker image and then from the script (inside Docker) run something like

`docker run postgres:9.6.3-alpine psql`

`docker run node:9.8 npm`

In other words would be to run docker inside docker. What do you think?

Comment: You can start by reading this question: [Is it ok to run docker from inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker) and I would continue with concepts like: `separation-of-concerns`, `fat-vs-lean images` and this article mentions a few good points [How to Not Be the Engineer Running 3.5GB Docker Images](https://www.datawire.io/not-engineer-running-3-5gb-docker-images/)

Comment: I've already read that article

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute docker run inside a docker, just **execute first docker run with** `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` option.

With this, you can access in containers to docker images defined in host or wherever.