# Running docker-compose in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, drone.io

basically what I'm wanting to do is run [Drone CI](https://drone.io) on a [Now](https://now.sh) instance.

Now accepts a Dockerfile when deploying, but not a [docker-compose.yml file](issue number), drone is configured using a docker-compose.yml file.

Basically I'm wanting to know whether you can run a docker-compose.yml file as part of a Dockerfile and how this is setup, currently I've been trying something like this:

```
FROM docker:latest

# add the docker-compose.yml file to the current working directory
WORKDIR /
ADD . /

# install docker-compose
RUN \
  apk add --update --no-cache python3 && \
  pip3 install docker-compose

RUN docker-compose up
```

and various variations of the above in my attempts to get something up and running, in the above case it is complaining about the docker daemon not running

Any help greatly appreciated, other solutions that acheive the above end result also welcomed

Comment: There is already something similar here about runing docker inside of a docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to run docker from inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile is creating docker container and in that container you are using docker-compose

1. you dont have docker daemon running inside docker container
2. docker compose also needs to be installed
   refer this doc https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/ to use docker in docker