# Using docker in docker from node:alpine image

Tags: node.js, image, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm currently trying to reduce the docker image size for my project and I started to do so by using the node:alpine image. I've started to run into a problem however, where I can't perform any docker commands from within the initial docker container. The command I'm running is:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ if eq .Destination "/database" }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}{{ end }}' MyContainer
```

When I try to run that command I get `/bin/sh: docker: not found` as an error. I'm using a Dockerfile to create the initial container, which looks like this:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add docker
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "startpro"]
```

I am not too sure if maybe I'm installing docker wrong or if docker in docker isn't supported within the node:alpine image. This was all working when I was using the node:latest image.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you don't have docker installed. Which OS are you using to run docker?

Comment: I'm using Linux.

Comment: Try installing Docker CE first, as it seems to me the needed packages aren't installed: https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/.

Comment: I have Docker CE installed, but it still doesn't work... Same error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just reread the question. You want to run docker inside of a docker. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: This is for a simulation project. I need the ability to launch more containers from within a single container, since it'll be running from a parent-container when in production mode. So essentially, that docker inspect command needs to be able to function from within a parent container, but right now, it can't find docker.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seem that Alpine requires some additional steps to configure Docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099218/how-can-i-install-docker-inside-an-alpine-container.

Comment: I've attempted that as well, but it gives me the same error. No docker found.