# Can we run docker on already created image (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-image

1. First I have installed Docker on Windows 10 OS.
2. Then I have created image of Ubuntu.
3. Using `ubuntu` image I have installed docker using following commands on Ubuntu OS:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"

sudo apt update

apt-cache policy docker-ce

sudo apt install docker-ce
```

4. It works fine till yet.
5. But when I run `docker info` command  it gives me error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have tried every possible solution through internet, but it does not work, it keeps on giving me same message.

Tried with following recommendation as well but no luck:

For Ubuntu 16.04

Inside file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` change:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd fd://`

with

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`

Inside file `/etc/init.d/docker` change:

`DOCKER_OPTS=`

with

`DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"`

Please help me out and let me know if I am doing some thing wrong or its not possible.

Comment: So you want to run a docker instance in Ubuntu ? Kind of like this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: i think this nested virtualisation is only possible if you platform supports nested virtualisation which in windows host is not supported by default. On linux host for docker it is more reasy

Comment: Check out to run docker in docker [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker)