# Control docker swarm from within a running container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a few micro-services deployed as a stack on **docker swarm,** with **each micro-service** running in a **separate container**.

How do I **give commands** to the **swarm** from **within** one of the services running inside **a container** on the swarm manager host? e.g running "docker service update" command from within a container to update one of the services in the swarm.

I read somewhere that it can be done by bind mounting the docker socket using:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But this does not work for me. I get **docker not found** error upon trying to run docker command from within the container.

Comment: Only mapping the socket will not do it if you are missing the actual docker binary. Try to have your container based on docker-in-docker (dind) image.

Comment: @Mihai [https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003273] this says (dind) should be avoided and that only bind mounting the socket should work.

Comment: of course, but if you  ask me I would also not try to change the swarm from within the swarm. In any case, if you don't want to use dind then you have to either manually install docker inside your container or map the binary from your host system (if you are using the same OS of course) inside the container