# Jenkins on Docker start build angular app on docker

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins

I started learning how to use Jenkins
I launched it on Docker.
I have a project written in Angular and a Dockerfile created in it to build a Docker image. When I try to boot from Jenkins, I get information that the docker is not installed. So I tried to install it but I can't manually install it. Can anyone suggest how to do this?
I say in advance that I would like to skip DockerHub

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding things correctly, you want to use Jenkins (running within a container) to build other container images. If that's correct, try one of the following:

1. [Docker-in-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker)
2. [Bind-mounting the docker socket](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337) into your Jenkins container
3. Install Jenkins directly on the host and add the user that Jenkins is running under to the `docker` group.

Do your research on each of these approaches - there are security risks that come with them. Understand your use case, understand mitigation approaches, and decide whether the risk is worth it.