# Docker in docker on a --create-with-container gce leads to Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to run docker in docker on a gce but to no avail.
I have used similar setup on a host and it worked fine. 
However, when try it with `--create-with-container` I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have docker installed in the image. It works fine when the image is run on a normal host.
Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
gcloud compute instances \
  create-with-container docker-in-docker-on-cge \
  --container-restart-policy=never \
  --container-privileged \
  --container-mount-host-path=host-path=/var/run/docker.sock,mount-path=/var/run/docker.sock \
  --container-mount-host-path=host-path=/usr/bin/docker,mount-path=/usr/bin/docker \
  --container-image=$MYIMAGE
```

Do you think this is possible at all, and if yes, what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a command `gcloud compute instances create-with-container` to create a GCE VM instance running a container image, a Container-Optimized OS (COS) is deployed. This is operating system optimized for running Docker containers. But it lacks many of components you had in a typical Linux distribution.

It has a number of limitations, for instance the COS kernel is locked down; you are unable to install third-party kernel modules or drivers. Containerized applications that depend on kernel modules, drivers and other additional packages that are not available in COS might not work. This is kind of a lockdown environment with a small attack surface, that runs your containers as safe as possible.

For more details please see [Container-Optimized OS Overview](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits)

It's unlikely that Docker-in-Docker configuration in COS is supported by Google.

Apart from that there are good explanations of why running a nested Docker configuration is troublesome and what a workaround could be:

[Is it ok to run docker from inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003273/11602913)

[Docker in Docker?](https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd)

Both listed above are based on the original article of the author of the Docker-in-Docker feature  Jérôme Petazzoni: [Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment? Think twice.](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)