# docker pull to also get postgres dependency image?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

New to Docker

**Background:** I have written a *docker-compose.yml* which when run with **docker-compose up** will build and run nicely on my box. Note: my **docker-compose.yml** downloads the **Postgres** image.

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
     image: conference_api 
     container_name: conference_api
     build:
       context: .
     ports:
       - 5000:80
     environment:
       ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
     depends_on:
       - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.3
    container_name: conference_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: conference
      POSTGRES_USER: conf_app
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I then publish my docker image to docker hub.

On a **fresh machine** I use **docker pull** to pull my image and then I run it.

I get errors saying bascially "I can't find the database". The Postgres Image was not also downloaded.

**My Question:** When I pull my image, how can I get the Postgres image to also download as it is a dependency of my Image.

Comment: On the "fresh machine," why aren't you using `docker-compose up`? That should pull all the needed images when you run that.

Comment: I'm trying to get the big picture here. So when I publish an Image to Docker Hub, if it depends on 10 other images to run, I would need to give clients a docker-compose.yaml file to run my image?

Comment: @IanVink Yes, in-line a `docker-compose.yml` into the repo's (and thus, DockerHub's) `README.md`. In fact, your `conference_api` service requires *exactly this docker-compose* because it depends on a service called exactly `postgres` running on the default port. This is why I would expect to get a compose file and run `docker-compose up` instead of `docker pull`, which will just pull required base images anyway.

Comment: More big picture: we do this at my company, and we have many base images that are built upon to make different applications. The only use I have encountered for anyone to run `docker pull` was to update a base image whose version tag didn't change, or to pull the newest `:latest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `docker-compose pull --include-deps [SERVICE...]`.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/pull/):

> `--include-deps`          Also pull services declared as dependencies

This would require the users of your image to have your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Another option would be to use [docker in docker](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/), so `docker-compose.yml` would be inside your image where it will execute. [However, this appears to be discouraged, even by the developer who made this feature possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003273/3589609)

Comment: Do I then need to provide the docker-compose.yml to my users of my image? (Trying to understand the big picture here)

Comment: I'm open to being wrong about this - but as far as I know: yes, you will need to provide them with your `docker-compose.yml` to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Another option is running docker and docker-compose inside of docker, but this is discouraged.