# How to create a Debian docker container that can run docker containers?

Tags: docker, debian

I need a Debian container that can run containers itself (and has access to systemd). Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker) post, I have tried to run

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name debian-buster-slim -h 10-slim -e LANG=C.UTF-8 -it debian:10-slim /bin/bash -l
```

but the container cannot run docker containers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Comman docker is unknown