# How to scale docker-in-docker

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-in-docker

I am using a docker-in-docker setup, because I am creating apps as seperated docker-container. This means that one container is spawning other containers. As far as I understood kubernetes and all other Auto-scale Cloudservices, this is not possible.

Any suggestion how I can do that?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: docker-in-docker is not recommend. http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ You should take a look at kaniko. Except you are using docker images based on windows/.net

Comment: I'd recommend reevaluating whether you _need_ containers to launch other containers.  That can result in a system that's hard to test, it can be prone to leaking containers, and the mechanism for doing it is different on Kubernetes vs. plain Docker (and on plain Docker you can't do it without being able to easily root the entire host).  DinD – running a separate nested Docker daemon – isn't part of this.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker) might be useful. Can you check and confirm.