# How to build from docker file inside another docker container?

Tags: docker

When I run:

`docker build -t random-letter .`

I get error:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I tried running `dockerd` but got some other errors

```
Running iptables --wait -t nat -L -n failed with message: `iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`, error: exit status 3
INFO[2022-04-13T14:32:13.795289191Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
INFO[2022-04-13T14:32:13.795587753Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
INFO[2022-04-13T14:32:13.795630880Z] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
WARN[2022-04-13T14:32:14.796355453Z] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting...  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok to run docker from inside docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003273/10743722) may help you to get a good answer since I believe DinD should be avoided to reduce complexity

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate, instead of posting an answer with just a link.

Comment: I have docker inside docker inside docker so its not working