# Error: stat /mnt/jenkins-store: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-eks

Very confused, I used an ec2 instance to bootstrap an eks cluster and everything worked completely fine yesterday. I deleted that cluster last night, just spun a new one up and now I'm getting this error when trying to build my jenkins pod

```
Error: stat /mnt/jenkins-store: no such file or directory
```

I find it strange how this error didn't show up yesterday and I set everything up the exact same way today. That error is what I got when I described my jenkins pod.

Here's my jenkins.yaml file for reference

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods","services"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["persistentvolumeclaims"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
---
# Allows jenkins to create persistent volumes
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to read secrets in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-crb
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  namespace: default
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: jenkinsclusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  # "namespace" omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: jenkinsclusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["persistentvolumes"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlp-port
              containerPort: 50000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var
              subPath: jenkins_home
            - name: docker-sock-volume
              mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        # This allows jenkins to use the docker daemon on the host, for running builds
        # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker
        - name: docker-sock-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: jenkins-home
          hostPath:
            path: /mnt/jenkins-store
      serviceAccountName: jenkins
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: ui
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 31000
    - name: jnlp
      port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
  selector:
    app: jenkins
---
```

Comment: What was the missing option when you re spawn your ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/542529/783), check if your `ec2-run-instances` launched as your new ec2 spawned instance should not include some volumes, which would be then used by the `jenkins.yaml`.

The lack of such a volume would explain the `Error: stat /mnt/jenkins-store` message.