# How to run systemd in Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, systemd, init

I want to run docker daemon using `systemd docker start` but there's no systemd in docker container. I can't use dind images because the the container is based on a different image and changing base image would require lot of work.

I don't want to mount /var/run/docker.sock as I can access images and container inside the host VM.

Please help me in running docker inside a docker container.

Tried running `systemd docker start`. Doesn't work because the PID=1 is the CMD=[start.sh] in the Dockerfile.

Comment: You want to run Docker in a container...in Docker?

Comment: Note there's usually only the absolute minimum inside a container by design, and there certainly won't be `systemd` present. Docker itself acts as a sort of higher-level `systemd`, starting and stopping *containers*, not processes.

Comment: Yes I want to run Docker inside a container.. in docker. This might sound weird but I have this use case and can't do anything about it.

Comment: You can think of it as each container is assigned to a user as an isolated work environment. They must be able to use docker to build and test their code.

Comment: I mean [good luck with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker) I guess.