# Jenkins Docker Container doesn't find docker.sock

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have following docker-compose

```
networks:
  myjen:
    external: false

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
    - .jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client
    - .jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - myjen
```

When I access the bash with

```
docker exec -it ID /bin/bash
```

it says

```
bash: docker: command not found
```

My goal is to access docker but not installing it on jenkins. Later I want this pipeline to run since it can't access docker it also doesn't work.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'dotnet --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tryied to run the container with privileged options but it also didn't work. My host machine is Windows 10.

Comment: I suppose there is no path like `/var/run/docker.sock` on Windows, it has to be something different. And keep in mind that your current setup becomes Docker in Docker that is [not recommended in general because of its implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879713/is-it-ok-to-run-docker-from-inside-docker#:~:text=Running%20Docker%20inside%20Docker).

Comment: By the way, Jenkins documentation specifically recommends a different way of installation [on Windows](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/#on-windows).

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev "Docker in Docker" usually means running a second Docker daemon in a container.  That can be complex, and leads to confusion about which copy of Docker you're working with.  Bind-mounting the host's Docker socket as in the question is usually (up to security concerns) the preferred alternative.