# Is there a way to nest docker build commands?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile builds a library whose [build script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/linux/libtensorflow_gpu.sh) uses the `docker build` command internally. Such nesting does not seem supported: [Ubuntu 18.04 image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/18.04/images/sha256-9bcfcd2cbadc77f41dd75535f694f2a5809f53eb2f6682398cedc1b6469ef783?context=explore) fails with `docker: command not found` and [installing Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) changes the error message to `/tmp/docker.sock: no such file or directory`.

The `docker run` command offers several ways to [nest containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721929/657401):

1. [running the outermost `docker run` command in privileged mode](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/),
2. [sharing the `/var/run/docker.sock` socker](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/#the-socket-solution) with containers.

Is any similar option available for `docker build`?

Comment: Maybe docker [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) can help?

Comment: Not without tinkering with the build script of the library, I would imagine. The build script does more than run `docker build`, so I would like to run it unedited and containerized.